# Connecting to FTP server giving error "ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"

Tags: php

When i try to connect to FTP server using

> ftp_ssl_connect()

, it is giving me this error

> ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /home/web/public_html/FTP.php on line 9

Here is my source code

```
    <?php

// set up basic ssl connection
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($host,'990','20');

// login with username and password
$ftp_user_name='user';
$ftp_user_pass='pass';
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (!$login_result) {
    // PHP will already have raised an E_WARNING level message in this case
    die("can't login");
}

echo ftp_pwd($conn_id); // /

// close the ssl connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

I saw many question like this, but not given me any appropriate answers, please help.

Comment: `ftp_ssl_connec` returns `false` when unable to connect through ssl instead use `ftp_connect`;

Comment: Actually my FTP connection will work by FTP over TLS, so i used it.

Comment: is port 990 open on your server??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this, actually my FTP connection is implicit FTP over TLS, so have to use CURL instead of ftp_connect and ftp_ssl_connect.
I did it like below

```
$fp = fopen('/', 'r');
$ftp_server = 'ftps://'.$server.'/'.$filename;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$user.':'.$pass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
//var_dump(curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```